# Find a specific word in text, and add link(Vuejs)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, hyperlink, href, keyword

In res.data.tweets i am fetching tweets from server and storing values for every tweet in tweetData obj. In tweet_text, i would like to add a link to the tagged twitter users(clickin on tag will redirect to twitter profile). I figured out how do i find tagged users but i am not able to add a link either with .link or .href attribbute.

```
    axios.post(API_URL, null, { params }).then(res => {
        this.currentPage = res.data.page
        this.numberOfPages = res.data.numberOfPages

        res.data.tweets.forEach(tweet => {
          const tweetData = {
            id: tweet.id,
            tweet_text: tweet.tweet_text,
            twitter_name: tweet.twitter_name,
            twitter_username: tweet.twitter_username,
            added_at: moment(String(tweet.added_at)).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm'),
          }
          this.tweets.push(tweetData)
          // Below this line i am trying to achieve something by adding a link
          this.tweets.forEach(el => {
            el.tweet_text.split(' ').forEach(word => {
              if (word.includes('@')) {
                // word = 'this is tag'
                word.link('https://twitter.com')
                console.log(word.link)
              }
            })
          })
        })
    })
```

This is component where data is shown

```
        <div class="tweets-container">
          <div
            v-for="tweet in tweets"
            :key="tweet.id"
          >
            <div class="tweet-card">
              <div class="username-time">
                <div class="user-info">
                  <p class="name">
                    {{ tweet.twitter_name }}
                  </p>
                  <p class="user-info-p">
                    @
                  </p>
                  <p class="username">
                    <a
                      :href="'https://twitter.com/' + tweet.twitter_username"
                      class="twitter_link"
                      target="_blank"
                    >
                      {{ tweet.twitter_username }}
                    </a>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="time">
                  <p>{{ tweet.added_at }}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                <p>{{ tweet.tweet_text }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What you've got looks correct, are you sure that `tweet.twitter_username` has the expected value? What result do you get with the current code? Does it render, is the link visible, clickable, any errors, etc?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My question is not about what you mentioned above because, tweet.twitter_username(this is who posted the tweet) is a different from tweet.tweet text, and this link is working. What i want to achieve here is that in tweet_text(where twitter_username mentioned someone, example @elonmusk) i want to click at this tag(elonmusk) and redirect to his twitter profile. I hope this is clear now.

Comment: So for example if twitter_username(CNN) tweet this(tweet_text): "@elonmusk bought a twitter". I want to be able to click at @elonmusk and be redirected to his twitter profile

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's going to work this way.

You should use a computed property which will append the username to the twitter base link. Then, in your template, you can link the href property to the computed property.

```
computed: {
    userLink: function () {
      return "http://twitter.com/" + this.tweet.twitter_username
    }
  }
```

You can now use this "userLink" directly in your template.

```
<p class="username">
  <a
    :href="userLink"
    class="twitter_link"
    target="_blank"
  >
   {{ tweet.twitter_username }}
   </a>
</p>
```

I didn't test the code I wrote, feel free to let me know if you need further advice ;)

Comment: twitter_username link is working, maybe what you mentioned there is a little bit better approach for making this work, but for now i am good with my code. Please read my response to Lissy93 to better understand what i want to achieve here, thank you.

Comment: Allright my bad didn't read the answer !
Try to store the "non tags" text in an array, and the "tags" in another array (save the position)
Then display the normal text, and use the "document.createElement()" method to create the link
You'll need to do some research here and take some time to get the proper logic but I think that could work